# Expand horizontally not vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you can see on the gif below, my `Tabs` are expanding vertically. However I want them to expand horizontally. I already tried with `white-space:nowrap`, and other things that proved to work for other people, but it just doesn't work in my case.

[Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqGYb.gif)

HTML:

```
<div class="l_tabs">
  <div>
    <ul id="myTab1" class="nav nav-tabs bordered">
      <li class="tab-add">
      <li class="contentTab">
      <li class="contentTab">
      <li class="contentTab">
      <li class="contentTab">
      <li class="contentTab">
      <li class="contentTab active">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.l_tabs {
    background: #474544 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 57px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
}
.l_tabs > div {
    background-color: white;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 99%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't provide the CSS for the li, but I guess there's a float assigned to it, that's why the div stacked to bottom, you need to remove it and apply display: inline-block instead.

```
.tab-add,
.contentTab {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your width in `.l_tabs{ }`

```
width: 500px;
```

to

```
width: 100%;
```

**Updated**

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrpHv/77/) for your reference.

That would do it!

Comment: can you post fiddle or so?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fiddle. I just added styles to your li element, check if that could help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.l_tabs > div {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Full Code:

```
.l_tabs {
    background: #474544 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 57px;
    width: 500px;
}



.l_tabs > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 40px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}


.l_tabs li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 50px;
}
```

> Ref: https://jsbin.com/gogayo/edit?html,css,output